# Hover/scale transform background image

Tags: css, hover, scale

I have used the code below to create a row of image holders which can be either portrait or landscape. I can't work out how to now apply a hover scale transform to each image (larger). 
Here is the code:

```
    <ul>
    <li>
        <div style="width:150px; height:150px;
           background: url('img/2.png') no-repeat center;
           border:1px solid red;">
        </div>
    </li>


    <li>
        <div style="width:150px; height:150px;
           background: url('img/1.png') no-repeat center;
           border:1px solid red;">
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div style="width:150px; height:150px;
           background: url('img/3.png') no-repeat center;
           border:1px solid red;">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li div:hover{
    transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I now have a problem with resolution - the background image size can't be changed so how do I scale up to a bigger version?

Comment: can you explain yourself a bit better?

Comment: Thanks for getting back - this way uses a fixed size image - all my images can be no larger than 150px so if I apply a scale transform then I get a pixellated thumbnail. I would like to hover over the image and have the thumbnail transform into a higher res image. I have tried hiding a high res image but it isn't a smooth transition at all. It seems that maybe the background image idea works for the portrait/landscape thing but not for the scaling. Sorry if I'm not clear.